# Getting ellipses function parameters without an initial argument

Tags: c++, parsing, variadic-functions

So I've been making a custom parser for a scripting language, and I wanted to be able to pass only ellipses arguments. I don't need or want an initial variable, however Microsoft and C seem to want something else. FYI, see bottom for info.

I've looked at the va_* definitions

```
#define _crt_va_start(ap,v)  ( ap = (va_list)_ADDRESSOF(v) + _INTSIZEOF(v) )
#define _crt_va_arg(ap,t)    ( *(t *)((ap += _INTSIZEOF(t)) - _INTSIZEOF(t)) )
#define _crt_va_end(ap)      ( ap = (va_list)0 )
```

and the part I don't want is the v in va_start. As a little background I'm competent in goasm and I know how the stack works so I know what's happening here. I was wondering if there is a way to get the function stack base without having to use inline assembly.

Ideas I've had:

```
#define im_va_start(ap) (__asm { mov [ap], ebp })
```

and etc... but really I feel like that's messy and I'm doing it wrong.

```
struct function_table {
    const char* fname;
    (void)(*fptr)(...);
    unsigned char maxArgs;
};
function_table mytable[] = {
{ "MessageBox", &tMessageBoxA, 4 } };
```

... some function that sorts through a const char* passed to it to find the matching function in mytable and calls tMessageBoxA with the params. Also, the maxArgs argument is just so I can check that a valid number of parameters is being sent. I have personal reasons for not wanting to send it in the function, but in the meantime we can just say it's because I'm curious.

This is just an example; custom libraries are what I would be implementing so it wouldn't just be calling WinAPI stuff.

```
void tMessageBoxA(...) {
// stuff to load args passed
MessageBoxA(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
}
```

I'm using the __cdecl calling convention and I've looked up ways to reliably get a pointer to the base of the stack (not the top) but I can't seem to find any. Also, I'm not worried about function security or typechecking.

---

edit: Thanks for input, it appears it wasn't possible.

My fix has ended up being

```
    #define im_va_start(ap) {\
        __asm push eax\
        __asm mov eax, ebp\
        __asm add eax, 8h\
        __asm mov ap, eax\
        __asm pop eax\
    }
```

And then I can continue as normal.

As for why I require it, I'm doing some (unique) read: unsafe tricks and using a struct array with a pointer to the function as defined above. Since each function is unique, and most are from my custom library, they have... different behaviors. I don't really know how to explain it, but I'll release the source when I finish the POC.

I'm not really worried about portability so that'll have to work. Also, for counting the args I did:

```
#define im_va_count(ap, num, t) {\
for(num = 0; *(t*)((ap += _INTSIZEOF(t)) - _INTSIZEOF(t)) > 0; ++num){ }\
--num;\
im_va_start(argptr);\
}
```

which works for me. If anyone's interested...

Comment: I have to ask, have you looked in to variadic templates? This is a good question by the way.

Comment: How is your function going to do anything if it knows nothing about the arguments being passed to it?

Comment: He obviously has some logic to do that in his program, this questioner doesn't appear ignorant enough to not think of something simple like that.

Comment: How will you know how many arguments are passed? Either information about the rest of the arguments has to be in one of the required arguments (as in printf's format string), or you scan arguments until you reach an end marker. Either way, there has to be at least one argument.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: I'm just curious.  I don't know how it would be done.  Having a global variable that indicates how many parameters are passed maybe?

Comment: @VaughnCato one way would the same way you know how many characters are in a C-string: a sentinel value.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: If that was the case, wouldn't you have to know that at least one parameter was being passed?

Comment: @VaughnCato that's just one way, there are obviously others that could be imagined, but this isn't possible anyway.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: I'm thinking there might be a conceptual issue.  Maybe he has functions that take a specific number of parameters, and he's just trying to store them in a generic table.  If that is the case, then it seems like he should be casting the function with specific parameters to a generic function type instead of trying to create a variadic function.

Comment: @VaughnCato yeah, I have no idea what he could be doing, but there are so many things that you could be doing that I tend to just try to  treat people like adults, answer questions as they are presented (unless they are very blatantly misguided) and not try to second-guess. I am not smart enough for that.

Comment: Naw, it's a POC and the functions can take any number of parameters. I'm not really interested in the number of parameters passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible, the C standard says:

> A function may be called with a variable number of arguments of varying types. As
>   described in 6.9.1, its parameter list contains one or more parameters.

And the `...` doesn't count as the "one or more parameters". Further,

> The `va_start` macro shall be invoked before any access to the unnamed arguments.

That it should be called like

```
va_start(va_list, parmN)
```

And that

> The parameter `parmN` is the identifier of the rightmost parameter in the variable
>   parameter list in the function definition (the one just before the `, ...`).

So as you can see, you cannot have a variadic function without at least one parameter before the ellipsis in standard C++. The non-portable assembly trick is the closest you can come.